# WPF: Binding to a Directory

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Is there an example somewhere of binding, a `ListBox` for example, to a directory? I'm guessing this will involve actually binding to something involving `FileSystemWatcher` so that the `ListBox` is updated accordingly.

Comment: What do you want in listbox? File names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know that you can bind to a directory. However, you can bind to an `ObserveableCollection` and then use the `FileSystemWatcher`'s events to update that `ObserveableCollection`, which in turn will update your listbox.

Comment: @dharmatech That's fine. I always mention it for the benefit of the user, both yourself in this instance, and the future folks that come here. I know I always look at the accepted answer first. Glad this helped you, man. Good luck out there.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using .NET 4 you can use new [Directory.EnumurateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571.aspx).

as it returns IEnumerable you might need to wrap it up with ObservableCollection to make it WPF MVVM friendly